# Android L inserts unwanted Intent Extras

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bundle

My app has been chugging along happily on Android Kitkat and below. However I started getting complaints from Android L users that it crashed on their device.

A surprising thing happened while debugging my app on Lollipop. While the debugger was attached to the app (i.e. I ran the app from Eclipse) the app didn't crash.

However when I killed the debugger and ran the app on the emulator, it crashed.

I discovered that Android L was inserting an intent.

I was only checking whether the bundle extra wasn't null. It wasn't, so when I tried to access my intent, the app crashed.

I tried to log that extra and received

```
{profile:0}
```

My question is, why does this happen on Android Lollipop? This doesn't happen in any other Android version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android Lollipop, you can use [Managed Profiles for Enterprises](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-compatibility.html).
So far I didn't find a way of extracting "profile" key name from Android SDK, so I need to hardcode it :(